# Python project structure for package with plugin classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory-structure, python-packaging

I'm just starting a new open-source Python (3) project. However my Python scripting has so far always been limited to one single file. I'm trying to make an installable package (installable through PyPi) Which then can be imported in some one else his own script after installing the package using `pip3`.

This is my current project tree.

```
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── library
    ├── CHANGELOG.txt
    ├── LICENSE.txt
    ├── MANIFEST.in
    ├── README.txt
    ├── setup.py
    └── my-module
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── plugins
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── some-plugin.py
        └── my-module.py
```

Information and reasoning about the structure.

- First level is just for the GitHub repo.
- Second level (library folder) is the package itself which will be uploaded to PyPi.
- Third level (my-module) is the actual module directory containing the main script `my-module.py` which in the end will be imported in the users his script.
- Fourth level (plugins) Will contain all the plugin classes for the script. The idea is to isolate most of the logic with the plugins.

An example of how I have the inner workings in mind.

Example plugin `some-plugin.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tweepy


class MyFirstPlugin:
  def __init__(self):
      self._consumer_key = None
      ...

  # Getters.
  @property
  def consumer_key(self):
      return self._consumer_key
  ...    

  # Setters.
  @consumer_key.setter
  def consumer_key(self, value):
      self._consumer_key = value
  ...

  # Deleters.
  @consumer_key.deleter
  def consumer_key(self):
      del self._consumer_key
  ...

  def do_magic(self):
      return "Some magic logic"
```

Example of the `my-module.py` code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import plugins.some-plugin as somePlugin

t = None
def setupTwitter(consumer_key, ...):
    t = somePlugin.MyFirstPlugin()
    t.consumer_key = consumer_key
    ...

def getTwitterFollowers():
    return t.do_magic()
```

Example usage of the package `my-awesome-script.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import my-module # after installing it with pip3

my-module.setupTwitter('my super secret consumer key', ...)
followers = my-module.getTwitterFollowers()
```

Few questions:

1. Is the general idea of using classes to isolate parts of the code from the main module a good idea/practice in Python? And is the way I did it in my example a good approach?
2. Is the folder structure in line with how a package should be written? I'm having a hard time finding a good example and documentation about it.
3. Are the classes with the getters/setters/deleters a commonly used tactic?

Now I can see a lot of personal opinions about my questions, but I'm more looking towards the recommended solution/best practices. Other recommendations are always welcome as well. I want to make sure I have the basic structure right before I really start working on it.

Comment: I tend to go with https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/, but recommendations and best practices are still based on opinion.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for that, seems like a very good and detailed blogpost. Going to read it completely over the weekend :)

Comment: In your example - you aren't writting getters and setters - you are writing properties - and they are good practice. Especially as they alllow you to extend that functionality if neccessary - checking for illegal values, combining 'private' attrributes in useful ways etc etc.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Yeah indeed, I searched for the Python way of implementing Getters and setters aka properties :). I'll indeed add more logic to the functions and such.